# Not the whole button changes on hover

Tags: css, button

When I hover over the 'Read my story' button in my about section on my homepage (https://howtogetrippedathome.com/), something strange happens.
When I hover the side of the button, only the button as a whole changes to red (but the text doesn't turn white). When I quickly hover over the text in the button, the text and the background of the text chagne color, but the rest of the button just slightly after.

I have read dozens of posts and tried everything, but I cannot make it work. I think it has to do with the element I am targeting, but I don't know how to do it right.

I use the following code:

```
.so-widget-sow-button .ow-button-base :hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff2828;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Help is very much appreciated, as I am kind of lost by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the colors from the `span`, because you need the hover to be an your `a` tag to change

```
.so-widget-sow-button .ow-button-base :hover {
    color: #fff; *--->remove this*
    background-color: #ff2828;
    transition: .3s; *---> change transition with 0.3s as it is on your a tag*
}
```

2) Add the new hover on your `a` tag an change to color of the `span`

```
.so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:hover span {
   color: #fff;
   transition: .3s;
}
```

3) Remove `!important` from the styling of the anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

I found this css in your stylesheet:

```
.so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:visited,
.so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:active,
.so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:hover {
            color: #ff2828 !important;
}
```

which as you can see forces the text color of hovered links inside `ow-button-base` as red. Removing the `a:hover` line solves the conflict; I was able to solve the problem also adding this css:

```
.ow-button-base a.ow-icon-placement-left:hover {
  color:white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:hover {
    color: #ff2828 !important;
}
```

It's overriding the color you put here.

```
.so-widget-sow-button .ow-button-base :hover {
    color: #fff;  <--- This one
    background-color: #ff2828;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Make it stronger and/or remove the `!important`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can't find the the first code you copied, it is not in my additional CSS section, so I don't know how to remove the !important unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have used color important in hover state of anchor,
please try below css that will resolve your issues.

.so-widget-sow-button-wire-95a2a00335aa .ow-button-base a:hover > span{color:#fff}

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I use this solution, the text turns white, but only the square directly behind the text gets red, not the whole button. It does work when I do this:

    .so-widget-sow-button .ow-button-base a:hover > span{
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #ff2828;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .so-widget-sow-button .ow-button-base a:hover {
    background-color: #ff2828;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

Comment: I'm sorry, I try to make it show up as code, but can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the "a" tag color with **.ow-button-base:hover** selection

```
.ow-button-base:hover > a
{
  color:#fff;
}
```

and also remove

```
color:#ff2828 !important
```